# If image in image source filename starts with specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply some script to only those img tags which has image filename starting with text item.

```
<img src="site.com/others.png">

<img scr="site.com/item1.png">       
<img scr="site.com/item2.png">
<img scr="site.com/item3.png">
```

So i only want to perform some task to these three image tags which have image name starting with item. how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This querySelector should work:

```
// vanilla
var items = document.querySelectorAll('img[src*="/item"]');

// jquery
$('img[src*="/item"]')
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp

### Edit

I added a `/` before `item` in the selector to only get ones that **start** with item.

### Edit 2

To answer your question about `this`. What your code is doing is:

1. Checking if any of the items exist
2. Trying to find the src of `this` which is the `window`
3. Then trying to change the src of the `window` (`this`).

Here is how you could change the src of each item:

```
// Find the items
var items = $('img[src*="/item"]');

// Create a function to change their src
function changeSrc(index, item) {

    // get the original src
    // I've added the replace at the end with a regexp to only get 
    // the filename and not the whole src path
    var filename = $(item)
        .attr('src')
        .replace(/.*\//, '');

    // Change the src
    $(item).attr("src","<?php echo $mediaDirectory;?>/"+filename);
}

// If there are items
if (items.length > 0) {

    // Run the changeSrc function for each one
    $.each(items, changeSrc);
}
```

Comment: "this" keyword is not working anymore with this selector.?

Comment: It might be a scope issue with `this`. Can you post your code?

Comment: if($('img[src*="item"]').length>0){
                   var filename= $(this).attr('src');
                   $(this).attr("src","<?php echo $mediaDirectory;?>/"+filename);
                   
                 }

Answer (score 1):

If you want the items where the **image name** of the source of the image **starts with** item and not get all imges that have `item` somewhere in their source url you can do the following:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('img[src]')]
.filter(
  img=>
    img.src.split("/").slice(-1)[0].indexOf("item")===0
);
```

Comment: Check the edit on my answer. Filling and filtering an array, then splitting and slicing can be avoided.